# How to pass authorization token in request using Request Specification Class in Rest assured API testing. How to use rest specification builder class

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to pass authorization token in rest assured using rest assured specification class. But I am getting authentication failed message below is my code.

```
     String Jsonbody="{\"name\":\"Vishwamitra Pillai\",\r\n"
            + "\"email\":\"pillai_vishwamitra@schmitt.info24\",\r\n"
            + "\"gender\":\"female\",\"status\":\"active\"}";
     String token="038f2fd3b9431b5fb34a889c9b4bf8eb29bcb72b16ea02535a151106bf94eff7";
     String authToken="Bearer"+token;

     RequestSpecBuilder reqSpeBuilder; 
     final RequestSpecification reqSpec;
     reqSpeBuilder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
     reqSpeBuilder.setBaseUri("https://gorest.co.in");
     reqSpeBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", authToken);
     reqSpec = reqSpeBuilder.build();

    RestAssured.given().spec(reqSpec).body(Jsonbody).
     when().post("/public/v2/users").then().log().all().statusCode(201);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add it as header.

```
reqSpeBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", authToken);
```

Your problem is here:

```
String authToken="Bearer"+token;
```

It should be like this:

```
String authToken= "Bearer " + token;
```

You have missed on space between Bearer and the actual token.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try and add the content type for the request

```
reqSpeBuilder.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

also try and change the response to

```
RestAssured.given().spec(reqSpec).body(Jsonbody).
     when()
    .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
    .post("/public/v2/users").then().log().all().statusCode(201);
```